# Best way to login?

Tags: php, authentication, admin

I'm new to php and would like some info please if its possible.
I'm currently trying to build a website for an excersise in my colledge.

My main question is which is the best or more professional way to create the login script (**note:** only one user, the admin will have access)???

- 1st by checking the data posted from the form if they match with
  those that are in a table 'admin' in database. so I have to create a table in my db and add one user only admin and then check with an sql query the match
- or 2nd by making a script like this:

  ```
  if(($_post['username'] == 'admin') && ($_post['password'] == 'password')){
      echo "Welcome admin";
  }else{
      echo "No access";
  }
  ```

Comment: Generally the former - in programming we try to avoid _hardwiring_, as it is considered inflexible. For login systems, try to avoid holding passwords in plain text (look up _hashing_ and _salting_) and ensure you don't have _SQL injection_ vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You could also secure the page with `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`

- [Apache Authentication, Authorization and Access Control <sup>apache.org</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html)
- [Password Protection with .htaccess & .htpasswd](http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html)

Comment: You can do that with more than one users, actually.

Comment: +1 In situations like the OP's this is a professional and easy solution. Writing an authentication system properly in PHP (and MySQL) is a very advanced task.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a `users` table? In that table, one field could be named "admin", with a "0" denoting not an admin and "1" representing admin.

For passwords, you will always want to use some sort of hash: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php.

Then, when checking login credentials, you can do

```
if( !empty($_POST['password'] && hash('sha256', $_POST['password']) = {database password}  ){
  // password's okay
}
```

- Never store plain-text/unsalted passwords in your database.

Note: Your database "password" will be the hashed/salted value, not the actual password.

Comment: I know this is homework, but if it was a real situation, I'd say "never store unsalted passwords in your database" too - as a variety of high-profile sites are discovering to their cost!

Answer (score 0):

Always better if you have your data in a database, and in this case you should encrypt your user data.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly should not store the password and the admin username in your code. Database is a  more secure and reliable storage for such data.

If you have a *users* table, you might have a field there indicating a level of user privileges, or you might even have a separate table with privileges. In that case, you could have an *admin* privilege and assign it to some user (one or more, as you wish).

Answer (score 0):

Of course first. In any moment you can add some users not by changing the source code, but by adding entry in database. Notice that sometimes we imply that only one user has access, but after we notice that another user must have access. Better to do it scalable.